# synchronising the alignment of the columns of two matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, alignment

I would like the columns to be aligned: the first raw "outside" the matrix should be aligned with the matrix below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$
};
\node (raw) at (a.west) {$
\begin{matrix}
\text{\ding{172}} \\
\text{\ding{173}} \\
\text{\ding{174}} \\
\text{\ding{175}}
\end{matrix}
$
};
\node (col) at (a.north) {$
\begin{matrix}
\text{\ding{172}} &
\text{\ding{173}} &
\text{\ding{174}} &
\text{\ding{175}} &
\text{\ding{176}}
\end{matrix}
$
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you do that with the `blkarray` package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `nicematrix`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\cdigit}[1]{\text{\ding{\numexpr171+#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
& \cdigit{1}
& \cdigit{2}
& \cdigit{3}
& \cdigit{4}
& \cdigit{5} \\
\cdigit{1} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\cdigit{2} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\cdigit{3} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\cdigit{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It has been already remarked that you can use `nicematrix`. However, a particularly nice aspect of `nicematrix` is that it introduces the counters `jCol` and `iRow` that can be used to avoid a lot of repetition. That is, you can use

```
code-for-first-row = \Circled{\scriptstyle\mathbf{\number\value{jCol}}},
code-for-first-col = \Circled{\scriptstyle\mathbf{\number\value{iRow}}}
```

to automatically create the entries. This works with `\cdigit` from the other answer, too, but I like `circledsteps` a lot because it is very customizable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{circledsteps}


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col,
    code-for-first-row = \Circled{\scriptstyle\mathbf{\number\value{jCol}}},
    code-for-first-col = \Circled{\scriptstyle\mathbf{\number\value{iRow}}}]
 & & & & &  \\ 
 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using the blkarray package works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
& \ding{172} & \ding{173} & \ding{174} & \ding{175} & \ding{176}\\
\begin{block}{c(ccccc)}
\ding{172} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\ding{173} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\ding{174} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\ding{176} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{blockarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]